# Find the smallest sum of multiples of two numbers that is still larger than another number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have two numbers $x$ and $y$, how do I find the smallest value of $ax + by$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers, such that $ax + by$ is still larger than another number $z$?

For example, imagine I have two types of drug vials, one holds 20mg and the other 50mg. How do I find the combination of these vials so that I have enough drug for some who needs, say, 80mg of drug, whilst minimizing waste?

I can of course do this specific example in my hand, but I need a generalizable algorithm that I can code into Python eventually. Thank you so much!

Comment: Are $x$, $y$ and $z$ integer? Are they positive?

Comment: Based on your example, we presumably also want $a,b$ non-negative.

Comment: By the linked dupe $\,a\Bbb Z + b\Bbb Z = \gcd(a,b)\Bbb Z\,$ so your  set of sums is simply the set of multiples of the gcd, so you seek the least multiple of the gcd larger than $\,z.\ \ $

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ must be non-negative you should look up the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem the Frobenius coin problem.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly to address the comments: In your example you can presumably use the vials to remove the drug as well as add it.  Thus we really are looking for integers $a,b$.  Note that we can always do all the adding first, and then the removing, so we never have to worry about "negative" quantities of drug.

The numbers of the form $ax+by$ are precisely the multiples of $\gcd(x,y)$.  This is due to [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#) - typically the first thing one is taught when studying number theory.

So the smallest such number greater than (or equal to) $z$ would be $\lceil z/\gcd(x,y)\rceil \times\gcd(x,y)$.

To work out $a,b$ you need to implement Euclid's algorithm, to find $a',b'$ such that: $$a'x+b'y=\gcd(x,y).$$

Then multiply your values of $a',b'$ by $\lceil z/\gcd(x,y)\rceil$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)